# Working with Spread Syntax ES6

Tags: javascript

I am using spread syntax to replace an object in an array but I can't the object is added as a new entry of my array.

```
state = {8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd:[
  {
    "id": "894tuq4ut84ut8v4t8wun89g",
    "parentId": "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd",
    "timestamp": 1503045227866,
    "body": "Hi there! I ams a COMMENTSsg.",
    "author": "thingtwo",
    "voteScore": 143,
    "deleted": false,
    "parentDeleted": false
  },
]}
```

First I find the index of the element that I want to replace with this function:

```
let index = state[payload.id].findIndex((element)=> element.id === payload.data.id)
```

And then I use the spread syntax to create a new state and replace the element inside of the array:

```
return { ...state,
                [payload.id]:[...state[payload.id],index=payload.data]
            }
```

But it returns this:

```
    {8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd:[
          {
            "id": "894tuq4ut84ut8v4t8wun89g",
            "parentId": "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd",
            "timestamp": 1503045227866,
            "body": "Hi there! I am a COMMENTS.",
            "author": "thingtwo",
            "voteScore": 143,
            "deleted": false,
            "parentDeleted": false
          },
          {
            "id": "894tuq4ut84ut8v4t8wun89g",
            "parentId": "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd",
            "timestamp": 1503045227866,
            "body": "Hi there! I am a COMMENTS Replace",
            "author": "thingtwo",
            "voteScore": 143,
            "deleted": false,
            "parentDeleted": false
          }
        ]}
```

The expected output:

```
{8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd:[
              {
                "id": "894tuq4ut84ut8v4t8wun89g",
                "parentId": "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd",
                "timestamp": 1503045227866,
                "body": "Hi there! I am a COMMENTS Replace",
                "author": "thingtwo",
                "voteScore": 143,
                "deleted": false,
                "parentDeleted": false
              }
            ]}
```

Comment: There is no "spread operator". There is "spread syntax", or "spread notation". Actually there is both "array spread syntax" and "object spread syntax", so it would be useful to be clear about which you are talking about.

Comment: Can you pls add expected output.

Comment: what is `data` in `index=data` ... did you want to assign the value of `data` to `index`?

Comment: @torazaburo I am guessing that kind of depends .. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/spread-operator-decrement-dot-dot-dot-javascript, and somehow the MDN URL ends in [/Operators/Spread_operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: Thank, for say me that is  "spread syntax" instead of "spread operator ", I edit the question, and include the expected output.

Comment: @Stai Well, anyone can put up any incorrect information they want. The fact remains that this is **not** an operator, which has a well-defined meaning (for instance, an expression involving an operator must result in a **value**). You will search the spec in vain for the term "spread operator". As for MDN, the page URL is merely a historical artifact. This has been a public service message from the Department of Extreme Pedantry.

Comment: [state[payload.id][index]] maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for updating properties of the found object (with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)).

```
let object = state[payload.id].find((element)=> element.id === payload.data.id);

Object.assign(object, payload.data);
```

Comment: I second this answer. In fact I was working on some similar sample, you can see the sample including quick fix in the array spread usage: https://jsbin.com/dolodof/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Spread syntax/operator is used to spread an object into comma separated keys.

In your state, every key is payload id and you want replace one entry in that payloads value, which is an array. So you need to go to that payload by id, go to the index in that payloads value array and replace that value with new value. below code should give you the expected output,

```
let index = state[payload.id].findIndex((element)=> element.id === payload.data.id);
state[payload.id][index] = payload.data;
console.log(state);
```

You should use spread syntax when you want to replace the complete array for that payload, and here you want to replace an entry in that array and not complete array.

## **Edit for avoiding mutation**

**1. Using Object.assign will mutate state,**

```
let index = state[payload.id].findIndex((element)=> element.id === payload.data.id);
let stateCopy = Object.assign({}, state);
stateCopy[payload.id][index] = payload.data;
console.log(state);
console.log(stateCopy);
```

*Check both state & stateCopy gets modified*

**2. Using spread syntax will mutate state,**

```
let index = state[payload.id].findIndex((element)=> element.id === payload.data.id);
let stateCopy = {...state}
stateCopy[payload.id][index] = payload.data;
console.log(state);
console.log(stateCopy);
```

*Check both state & staeteCopy gets modified*

**3. Use cloning to avoid mutation of original state,**

install esclone,

```
 #> npm install --savedev esclone
```

go to your file and add import,

```
 import esclone from "esclone";
```

And use below code to achieve the expected output without mutation,

```
let index = state[payload.id].findIndex((element)=> element.id === payload.data.id);
let stateCopy = esclone(state);
stateCopy[payload.id][index] = payload.data;
console.log(state);
console.log(stateCopy);
```

*Check original state is not modified*

**Note:** *Object.assign & spread syntax performs only a reference copy and not deep copy, hence you need to use some deep clone mechanism like esclone library.*

Comment: But you are mutating the state, is because that I use Spread Syntax, I don't want to mutate the state

Comment: In the end spread operator as well as object.assign does a shallow copy. I will check if i can improve my answer for your need. You may need to use cloning to avoid mutation.

Comment: Sorry but I disagree if you do:
`let state = {id:1, name:"james"}`
`let newState = {...state}`
`newState.id = 2`
`console.log(state.id) // -->1`
`console.log(Newstate.id) -->2`

That means the state never mutate using Spread.

Comment: Do you mean, you disagree that spread operator does a shallow copy ?

Comment: Yes, it returns a new object instead.

Comment: Here yo are not modifying any object referred by any of key of state, instead you are changing the reference now to point to a new object. It is a reference copy, stae.id & newState.id are two different references pointing to same object, if do not modify pointer of newState.id and instead change property of object pointed by newState.id then it will mutate state. For that we need id not to be a primitive value but nested key-value object.

Comment: Also please check official doc it says it is for shallow copy,

Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) or merging of objects is now possible using a shorter syntax than Object.assign().
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152317/discussion-between-jteam-and-steven-daniel-anderson).

Comment: Check this, here when you modify newState, state also gets modified, 
https://repl.it/KQ4p/0